# Converting a curl command to a .NET http request

Tags: c#, .net, rest, curl, dotnet-httpclient

Could someone please help me convert this curl command into a HttpClient/HttpRequestMessage format in .NET?

```
curl https://someapi.com/ID \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d '{"name":"test name"}' \
-X PUT
```

What I have so far is this, but it doesn't seem to be right:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
request.Properties.Add("name", "test name");
return await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
This example uses [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to serialize the string to a json format

Try:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var anonString = new { name = "test name" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anonString);

await client.PutAsync("URL", new StringContent(json)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it comes back with a "bad request" error.

Comment: @Prabhu of course, your curl code posts *json* data, but this answer tries to send *url-encoded* data.

Comment: I looked up the curl -d and it said: (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**